# How to iterate through a dict to see if a occurence of a list matches one or more of the keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
BACKPACK = {'granola bar': 1, 'cooked meat': 1, 'raw meat': 1, 'dried foods': 1}
```

What I want to do is check if one or more elements inside of a list occur in that dict, if so I want to go to the next method, if not I want to do something else.

```
BACKPACK = {'granola bar': 1, 'cooked meat': 1, 'raw meat': 1, 'dried foods': 1}
HEALTH = 25

def rest():
    print formatter()

    foods = ['granola bars', 'cooked meat', 'dried foods']

    for food in foods:
        if food in BACKPACK:
            eat_food(BACKPACK, HEALTH)
            break
        else:
            print "You don't have any food in your pack." \
                  " You decide to go hunting."
        #  go_hunting()

def eat_food(food, health):
    print food
    print health
```

What I want to do is print out a list of the available foods to be eaten, if the keys in the dict correspond with the list in the function.

For example if I have this:

```
BACKPACK = {'cooked meat': 1, 'raw meat': 1}
foods = ['granola bars', 'cooked meat', 'dried foods', 'raw meat']
```

This should output:

```
1. cooked meat
2. raw meat
```

I apologize for the confusion

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong? I tried running the code and it seems like it's working...

Comment: Sorry everyone I got really busy and accidentally hit 'ask question' I wasn't done writing the question. I finished and hope this clarifies some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: your loop was the wrong way use this

```
BACKPACK ={'cooked meat': 1, 'raw meat': 1}
HEALTH = 25





def rest():
    # print formatter()

    foods = ['granola bars', 'cooked meat', 'dried foods', 'raw meat']

    for food in BACKPACK:
        if food in foods:
            eat_food(food,HEALTH)
        else:
            print "You don't have any food in your pack." \
                  " You decide to go hunting."
        #  go_hunting()

def eat_food(food,health):
    #get rid of food
    #add health
    print food



rest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is *this* what you need?  It should work properly now:

```
BACKPACK = {'raw meat': 1, 'raw meat': 1, 'granola bar': 1, 'dried foods': 1, 'cooked meat': 1}
HEALTH = 25

def rest():

    foods = ['granola bar', 'cooked meat', 'dried foods']

    back = {}

for x in foods:
    for y in BACKPACK:
        if y in foods:
            back[y] = 1

for key, value in back.items():
    print("1. " + str(key))


def eat_food(food, health):
    print(food)
    print(health)

rest()
```

Comment: Sorry, read my comment above and look at the answer again. This is close, but I'm pretty sure I'll have to use `enumerate` somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get all keys that are in a list, you should use **sets**:

```
intersection = set(mylist) & set(mydict.keys())
```

If there aren't any, intersection will be an empty set with a false bool, otherwise it will have a true bool. To check whether there are such elementw you can therefore just write:

```
if intersection:
    do_sth
else:
    do_sth_else
```

Comment: Why use sets instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: Its easier, less complex and probably faster.

Comment: `You sit down and feel kind of hungry.`;`1 of raw meat`;`What would you like to eat:`

Comment: If I have this: `BACKPACK = {'cooked meat': 1, 'raw meat': 1, 'granola bars': 1}` and this: `foods = ['granola bars', 'cooked meat', 'dried foods', 'raw meat']` and use what you said: `intersection = set(foods) & set(BACKPACK.keys())` I get the output above instead of it listing all of the items that are in the `BACKPACK`